# Obtener el numero de días transcurridos entre dos fechas

Tags: jquery, html

Quiero obtener el numero de días entre dos fechas con jquery,

ejemplo tengo estas dos fechas:

```
var fechaI = '2017-09-01';
var fechaF = '2017-09-10';

//resultado
   var dias = "x numero de dias";
```

el problema es que no se como hacerlo en `jquery`  alguien que me pueda ayudar ¿?

Comment: Has intentado algo que no resulto?

Comment: jQuery es una librería de JavaScript muy popular pero esta no tiene métodos particulares para el manejo de fechas. Deberías agregar lo que has buscado/investigado sobre el tema.

Comment: [Esta es la misma respuesta de @EduenSarceño](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2609579/5587982) usando jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo que utilices la libreria [moment](https://momentjs.com/) para que te sea mas fácil manipular fechas. Con esta librería, lo que pides quedaría así:

```
const diff = moment("2017-09-10").diff(moment("2017-09-01"), 'days');
```

Comment: La pregunta trata sobre jQuery. ¿Qué tiene que ver moment con jQuery?

Comment: No tiene que ver, pero es una opción. No hay que tomarnos tan a pecho lo que dice el OP; personalmente me parece que el OP está recién empezando y no sabe diferenciar JavaScript de jQuery en su totalidad.

Comment: Recuerden que jQuery es una libreria JAVASCRIPT especilizada en manejar el DOM y moment es una libreria JAVASCRIPT para manipular fechas. Cada quien a lo suyo, es mi humilde opinión.

Comment: Para que @Rubén descanse, sugiero que el OP edite la pregunta, cambiando la etiqueta [tag:jquery]  por [tag:momentjs] o al menos dando las dos posiblidades, jQuery y/o momentjs

Answer (score 2):

Me temo que jQuery no tiene funcionalidades referentes al manejo de fechas, deberás descargar una biblioteca de terceros para éste mismo, no obstante, al no tratarse de DOM, lo mejor es hacerlo nativamente en lugar de un plugin a jQuery

La solución a tu problema es sencilla, sólo debes crear instancias de la clase [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Date), calcular la diferencia de ambas fechas (en milisegundos) y posteriormente hacer la conversión a días.

```js
var fechaI = new Date('Sep 01, 2017')
var fechaF = new Date('Sep 09, 2017')

var difM = fechaF - fechaI // diferencia en milisegundos
var difD = difM / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24) // diferencia en dias

console.log(difD)
```